# React.js onClick not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and was playing around with it, and I cannot figure out how to make a on click.

**EDIT** I think it might be worth mentioning that because of the lynda.com course and because I couldn't get any other version to work I am using react 0.13.3 production and babel 5.8.29.

I have this code.

```
    var Test = React.createClass({

        alert: function() {
            alert('HI');
        },

        render: function(){
            return ( 
                <div onClick={this.alert} id='test' className={this.props.id}>
                <span>{this.props.title}</span>
                <p>{this.props.desc}</p>
                </div>

                )
        }
    });
    React.render(<div>
                <Test title='Blog' desc='This is my blog' id='one'/>
                <Test title='Portfolio' desc='Check out my work!'id='two'/>
                <Test title='Fun and Games' desc='Games'id='three' />
                </div>, document.getElementById('test'));
```

but when I click the div here

```
                    <div onClick={this.alert} id='test' className={this.props.id}>
```

nothing happens

this

```
alert: function() {
            alert('HI');
        },
```

doesnt fire... Why?

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue?

Comment: jsFiddle, Chrome console adding some random debugging thingys. I cannot figure it out, no errors or anything. That is a strip down version of what I had I figured out what the problem was (it wasnt firing the onclick function) I just cannot figure why its not working

Comment: I just pasted your code in a fiddle and it works fine, React.render is deprecated though, You should use ReactDOM.render, fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/vwL4gzct/1/

Comment: Its not working on chrome lol? Or my jsfiddle let me see if I still have the jsfiddle

Comment: I dont have the jsfiddle sorry D:! also I am using react 0.13.3 production is the version the problem? it is the same version the lady has in the course and looking back she does the same thing with an alert and onClick div and it work fine,

Comment: this.alert is a reserved window function. Try naming it something else like this.handleAlertClick

Comment: did you click my fiddle link? here it is again: https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/vwL4gzct/1/